# How to close all children windows in browser on unload of parent window with javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, window.opener

I need to find and close all children windows (whose that this page is their window.opener) on unload of the page with javascript. When parent window is about to be unloaded I need to  run through all opened windows and close only those that the unloaded page is their window.opener. What is the correct way to do so ? I need a cross-browser solution .

Comment: without further research http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable for every new window you need to open, then close them  like this:

```
var.close();
```

Full example:

```
var window1; 
window1 = window.open("www.google.com");
window1.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making use of onunload event which is responsible for closing all the pop-ups.

`<body onunload="destroyPopUps()">`

In the code above the onunload event is tied to the body element of the page. Here is the implementation of the destroyPopUps function.

```
function destroyPopUps() 
{
    if(popups.length == 0) return; 
    for(i=0; i<popups.length; i++) 
    {
        popups[i].close(); 
    }
}
```